# OnTesterInit works too long

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

When running an optimization on Metrader 5 I get the following error message :

> OnTesterInit works too long...

This error occurs 5 times and is then followed the following :

> OnTesterInit works too long. Tester cannot be initialized.

There are only 9 steps in the optimization and date range is only a few days. Furthermore the server on which it is run is powerful and uses almost no resources for this process so what is working too long?

The only related [link](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mql5.com%2Fru%2Fforum%2F12179&edit-text=) that mentions this error message does not offer a solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all auto-generated methods that contain "test" solved the issue. All of those methods were empty so one would expect them to not *work* long.